# Do steep, 1200 meter high water waves ("rogue waves"), due to tidal effects, exist?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, estimation, tidal-effect

In a comment on another question, I saw the movie Interstellar mentioned. And I immediately thought about the scene in which some members of the discovery team had landed on a planet circling the black hole Gargantua. They landed in a thin layer of water on which a huge spiked wave (assumed to be 1200 meters high; see [here](https://www.space.com/28077-science-of-interstellar-book-excerpt.html#:%7E:text=In%20his%20new%20book%20%22The,4%2C000%2Dfoot%2Dtall%20)) appeared. Remember?
I can't imagine this to be true. Of course, there are tidal forces exerted by the black hole. And maybe there are more waves due to multipole tidal forces. Let's assume that the planet is not yet tidally locked to Gargantua. Can these waves actually exist? Can gravity be "concentrated" in such a small region? Or: Was Kip Thorne right in asserting that this wave(s?) can actually exist? Is general relativity essential for understanding this effect, if it indeed exists?

[image]

Of course, the huge waves could be used cinematically to give a feel for tidal effects, but then why Kip Thorne writes these spiked waves can actually exist. Or was he referring only to the height of the waves, and not to their spiky Nature?

In the picture, a small water wave is depicted. I think this wave is a tsunami on earth. So these huge waves **are** possible. They even can grow to 500 meters high! See the comment below by @Azur. Or see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ylOpbW1H-I). Of course. When a big meteorite hits the earth, huge waves will be produced. But these are easy to understand. What is difficult to understand is that spiky waves emerge due to a tidal effect.

Comment: Absolutely unrelated to the physics of it, but I recall reading an article (https://www.surfertoday.com/surfing/the-biggest-wave-ever-recorded-measured-1720-feet) about a wave higher than 500 meters (on Earth). I don't know what it's worth, and how much we can trust this source, but if that's true it's still kinda cool

Comment: @Azur Wow, that will be some trip! I'm sure these waves exist, but these are waves generated by "normal" processes. So don't forget your board when a meteorite hits the Earth... The waves I think about (which are the ones in the movie) are allegedly produced by the black hole's distortions of spacetime "surrounding" the planet.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not familiar enough with general relativity to answer... but I'm really interested in what will come up! (I was just sharing a cool article your post reminded me of :'))

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156577/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161004/123208